# Unity editor script to modify class properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a long array of a struct I created called Int2 (basically just holds an x & y int). I've used the `[System.Serializable]` directive and the struct works fine / shows in the editor etc. The array is in a class attached to an empty GameObject in each of my scenes.

To save some donkey work I created an editor script to populate these lists which appears to work just fine to change the values. However when I enter play mode or reload the scene the changes revert. Saving the scene & project makes no difference. The array is called 'waveBotTypes'.

```
[MenuItem("F_Tools/Wave_20_easy")]
static void Wave20Easy()
{
    F_LevelManager lvl = Selection.activeTransform.GetComponent<F_LevelManager>();
    lvl.numberOfWaves = 20;
    lvl.waveBotTypes = new Int2[20];
    for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++)
    {
        lvl.waveBotTypes[x] = new Int2((int)(x * 1.5) + 5, Random.Range(0, (int)(x / 5)));
    }
}
```

Any idea how to make the values stick? Thanks.

Comment: first declare them public and save the prefab after the editor changed the values. I use this method

Comment: Thanks, that works, though I I'd need a different prefab for each scene to have different values

Comment: saving as prefab is actually not necessary. I save them because I don't want to lose the data by accident. one could easily mess up the whole thing.